# Dynamic voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, brushless-dc-motor, voltage-measurement, motor-controller

I'm trying to build an ESC (electronic speed controller) for three phase brushless motor. I found some intresting circuits but I am trying to build something very easy to do, with mosfet and pc817 and an Arduino.

I am using the DAC of the mcu to sense the voltage of the motor in each coil. So far I had used a resistor divider and worked, but motors vary a lot in voltage range (some are of 11.1V, others even of 22V and more,) so using a resistor divider limitsit to a certain family of motors.

I want to know if it is posible to divide whatever the voltage enter to the DAC pin (40v max)  to 0 (or -5v) and 5v without losing the sine wave form.

Comment: DAC is a digital to analog converter. You mean ADC? An analog-to-digital converter? If so, yes you can scale down the voltage using a resistive divider so that the ADC can read the voltage.

Comment: You're going to have to limit the voltage range of your ESC anyway, because of the FETs that you pick.  If the ADC has sufficient resolution, a resistive divider suitable for the highest design voltage of your ESC should work over at least a 4:1 range of battery voltages.

Comment: -1 for very poor writing, missing capitalisation and punctuation. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the site rules

Comment: learn how to control accelertion and velocity with feedback before trying to design an ESC.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the resistor divider for the highest voltage possible. If your ADC has, let's say 12 bits, you'll be only missing 1 bit if the voltage is half the max case or 2 bits if the voltage is a quarter of the max case. Hopefully the remaining bits will be enough to do what you want.

Comment: mmm maybe you are right adc of mcu's had a lot of definition this days so a tiny loss its not the big deal, anyway puting something in between can be a good idea becouse voltage peaks can occur and fry the adc